# Bad display of errors messages

Tags: html, forms, css

I have encountered a problem while trying to display HTML5 error messages when submitting a form as shown in [this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqWRO.png):

The dark gray bar on top is my navigation bar.

The problem is that my form is a little long, so you have to scroll down to confirm. However, if one has not filled out a field that contains a required tag, the page will automatically slide up to show the error message. The problem is that the error message covers my navigation bar which holds a field for filling in the required information.

I'd like for my page scroll a little further so that both the navigation bar and error message are visible.

I also use bootstrapping.

Code from the comment below:

```
var animate = true;
$( "input,select,textarea" ).bind( "invalid", function() {
    console.log('Invalid');
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    offset.top -= 200;
    if (animate) {
        animate = false;
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: offset.top }, 10, function() {
            animate = true;
        });
    }
});
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Could please share some code?

Comment: var animate = true;
        $( "input,select,textarea" ).bind( "invalid", function() {
            console.log('Invalid');
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            offset.top -= 200;
            if (animate) {
                animate = false;
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: offset.top
                }, 10, function() {
                    animate = true;
                });
            }
        });

Answer (score 1):

try to add margin to the container element  and this will push you content down the navbar

```
 style="margin-top :100px;"
```